# Identifying Distributions from Sample Data

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So if one has a collection of data, how does one determine whether or not it follows a normal, weibull, gamma, beta, exponential, etc. distribution? From what I've read, one creates QQ-plots of the data against the distributions quantiles. This can be done in MiniTab19 using `Stat > Quality Tools > Individual Distribution Identification` (https://blog.minitab.com/blog/meredith-griffith/identifying-the-distribution-of-your-data).

However, how do these software's calculate the parameters for the distributions? For example, a Weibull has a scale and shape parameter, that can take any value. How do these software populate the weibull distribution quantiles in the plots with these paramaters? Do they just choose parameters that minimize some kind of error? If so, what is the Math behind this? I'm trying to implement this kind of procedure, discovering the distribution type of a sample of data, in my code.

Comment: It's a huge question. Maybe start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory . This is an important approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation